# Tangent even derivative

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that $\tan^{(2n)}(0)=0$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ? I can't quite see the inductive step (or maybe there's another way to do it).

Comment: The tangent function is *odd*, and has a power series that converges in some interval about $0$. Any such odd function $f$ has odd $(2n)$-th derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Andre's answer: There are two important facts in use here. (1) $\tan x$ is an odd function; and (2) $\tan x$ can be expanded in a power series with positive radius of convergence. Given these, suppose $\tan x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ in some region around $0$. Then

$$-\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=-\tan x=\tan(-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(-x)^n,$$

and by uniqueness of Taylor series, these expansions are term-by-term equal. Thus

$$-a_n=(-1)^na_n\implies a_n=(-1)^{n+1}a_n.$$

For odd $n=2k+1$, this just says $a_{2k+1}=a_{2k+1}$, but for even $n=2k$, $a_{2k}=-a_{2k}$ implies $a_{2k}=0$. Finally, use the relation $a_n=\frac1{n!}\tan^{(n)}0$ to show that the even derivatives of $\tan x$ vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by induction that every even derivative of tangent is a linear combinaion of odd powers of tangent.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Taylor series for $\tan{x}$. This is $$\tan{x} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{U_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + O(x^5)$$

Comment: The problem is for calculating the taylor series  you are using the result what is needed.

Comment: The series is not derived using that result.

Comment: And how is derived?